# Change of country but no translation in url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization

I have a country selector on my site that aims to come and modify my URL.
Example: https://test.fr/fr to https://test.es/es
The logic for this is here:

```
setLang(lang) {
  this.$i18n.setLocale(lang)
  this.$moment.locale(lang, this.$i18n.t('common.moment', lang))
  this.switchLocalePath(lang)
}
```

My problem is that the /lang at the end of my URL remains in the previous country

Example: https://test.fr/fr to https://test.es/fr to https://test.fr/es

If I add console logs to see what is happening, I have the impression that the problem comes from my route element which remains in the previous country

```
this.switchLocalePath(lang) /fr
route :  {name: 'index___es', meta: {…}, path: '/es', hash: '', query: {…}, …}
```

So I tried to do my switchLocalePath in my router but without success:

```
this.$router.push(this.switchLocalePath(lang))
```

How to solve this problem?